# 3 select boxes in a row in a single line?

Tags: php, html

it is only displaying the first select box and the last one ..
here is the code.

```
function select_nom_of_guests($guest_type){
    $i=0;
    echo $guest_type;
    echo "<select name=\"adults_num\" id= \"a\">";
    while ($i<=5){
        echo "<option value= $i>$i</option>" ;
        $i++;
    }
}

echo "<p>";
    select_nom_of_guests("מספר מבוגרים");
    select_nom_of_guests("מספר ילדים");
    select_nom_of_guests("מספר תינוקות");
echo "</p>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close your `<select>` tags and it should work better ;-)

Note that a for loop would be more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you don't end the `<select>` tag. I'm not sure how browsers would respond to that, but it definitely wouldn't help.

One helpful tool in these scenarios is the View Source tool that all major browsers have: instead of being confused about what's appearing on the screen, look at the HTML that the browser received to see why it might be showing what it's showing. If this is the issue, the source code would have revealed it lickity-split :)

Comment: @user605505: glad it could help :) Please click the check box on this post, to give me credit for a good answer and to make this question as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the `select` tag. You probably also want to make the `name` and `id` attributes different for each `select`.

```
function select_nom_of_guests($guest_type){
    $i=0;
    echo $guest_type;
    echo "<select name=\"adults_num".$guest_type."\" id= \"select_".$guestType."\">";
    while ($i<=5){
        echo "<option value= $i>$i</option>" ;
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```